# Powerbuilder in the modern Age vs C#/Java/C++ for a CS student

Tags: c#, sybase, popularity

this is the first time I ask something here. I've read a few topics of Powerbuilder.

I personally hate the language, it makes me more "stupid, less logic, more laziness".

Anyways, I'm a CS student (not from US/Canada), I'm from Panama, we're supposed to learn powerbuilder for two semesters, while we spent less time with java/C++.

Now I need opinions if my university should stop using powerbuilder (10.0) and switch to C#.
I heard they won't update their license, but they have installed VS 2010 full, just to teach C++/VB, without exploiting the other programming languages C#.

Most of students had to piracy PB to maker their homework at home, because the trial version won't last enough for the two semesters, I instead went in rebellion and started to use C#.

What I want to know this from all of you:

- Should we start to use another language
- Is powerbuilder powerful for other things (Driver, game making, etc).
- It is a waste of time to learn it
- Why the language suck or why it rocks
- Finally, do you think the school is rude for using a non open source or free alternative IDE's so the students can work better.

And yeah, there's a big group that is hating PB at the moment, so we're ready to give any evidence to the dean and the university owner so he change the study plan for the next semester, since we still have time to change the language, and it would be useful to have your opinions.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I have worked with PB7 and PB10 nearly 2 years and it was rather painful. Now I am very happy with C# for 3 years and I would never come back to PB.

- PB is old and not very well designed.
  E.g. support for OOP is loose; there
  are no “modern” functional features
  at all. Even there is no support for
  short circuit evaluation in the
  language so your code must be
  composed from deeply nested if
  statements in some cases. I cannot
  luckily remember any other language
  shortcomings but they are there for
  sure:). IMO PB forces you to use bad
  practices and it is very easy to make
  a big ball of mud from a larger
  project. There are definitely better
  ways how to learn programming than
  PB.
- The worst PB part was IDE in my eyes.
  It was horribly buggy and not very
  stable so I had to restart it
  frequently. Source code is stored in
  binary PBL files and cannot be edited
  in more reasonable tool so you are
  jailed in terrible IDE and the way to
  the freedom is difficult.
- PB is quite handy for simple data
  driven business applications but I
  can hardly imagine how to use it for
  anything else. I see development of
  nontrivial game as frustrating
  challenge (PB 11 with binding .NET
  could change something) and you
  cannot develop any drivers because PB
  program is executed in PB virtual
  machine. No experiences with web
  application development.

I do not know anything about the newest PB11. Something could be better there but the future is somewhere else:).